# C++/Cli synchronizing threads writing to file

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

I am trying to synchronize threads writing data to a text file in a class by using Monitor, but in my code it seems that the else statement is never evaluated, is this the correct use of monitor for thread synchronization?

```
void Bank::updatefile()
{
Thread^ current = Thread::CurrentThread; 
bool open = false;
current->Sleep(1000);
while (!open)
{
    if (Monitor::TryEnter(current))
    {
        String^ fileName = "accountdata.txt";
        StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
        for (int x = 0; x < 19; x++)
            sw->WriteLine(accountData[x]);
        sw->Close();

        Monitor::Pulse;
        Monitor::Exit(current);
        current->Sleep(500);
        open = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Monitor::Wait(current);
        current->Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an object to `Monitor::TryEnter` that is specific to the thread in which it is executing (i.e. `Thread^ current = Thread::CurrentThread;`).  No other threads are using the same object (they're using the one for their own thread).  So there's never a collision or locking conflict.

Try creating some generic object that's shared among the threads, something higher up in the `Bank` class.  Then use that for your `TryEnter` call.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `Monitor` is partially correct. The object you're using for locking is not correct.

### `Monitor`

`Monitor::Pulse` is unnecessary here. Just `Exit` the monitor, and the next thread will be able to grab the lock.

`Monitor::Wait` is incorrect here: `Wait` is supposed to be used when the thread has the object *already locked*. Here, you have the object not locked yet.

In general, `Pulse` and `Wait` are rarely used. For locking for exclusive access to a shared resource, `Enter`, `TryEnter`, and `Exit` are all you need.

Here's how your use of `Monitor` should be written:

```
Object^ lockObj = ...;
bool done = false;
while(!done)
{
    if(Monitor::TryEnter(lockObj, 500)) // wait 500 millis for the lock.
    {
        try
        {
            // do work
            done = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor::Exit(lockObj);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Check some other exit condition?
    }
}
```

or if the `else` is empty, you can simplify it like this:

```
Object^ lockObj = ...;
Monitor::Enter(lockObj); // Wait forever for the lock.
try
{
    // do work
}
finally
{
    Monitor::Exit(lockObj);
}
```

There is a class that Microsoft provides that makes this all easier: `msclr::lock`. This class, used without the `^`, makes use of the destructor to release the lock, without a try-finally block.

```
#include <msclr\lock.h>

bool done = false;
while(!done)
{
    msclr::lock lock(lockObj, lock_later);
    if (lock.try_acquire(500)) // wait 500 millis for the lock to be available.
    {
        // Do work
        done = true;
    }
} // <-- Monitor::Exit is called by lock class when it goes out of scope.

{
    msclr::lock lock(lockObj); // wait forever for the lock to be available.
    // Do work
} // <-- Monitor::Exit is called by lock class when it goes out of scope.
```

### The object to lock on

`Thread::CurrentThread` is going to return a different object on each thread. Therefore, each thread attempts to lock on a different object, and that's why all of them succeed. Instead, have one object, created before you spawn your threads, that is used for locking.

Also, instead of opening & closing the file on each thread, it would be more efficient to open it once, before the threads are spawned, and then just use that one `StreamWriter` from each of the threads. This also gives you a obvious object to lock on: You can pass the `StreamWriter` itself to `Monitor::Enter` or `msclr::lock`.